# Difficulty satisfying hard and medium constraints simultaneously with Optaplanner

Tags: constraints, scheduling, optaplanner

I've implemented a sensor scheduling problem using OptaPlanner 6.2 that has 1 hard constraint, 1 medium constraint, and 1 soft constraint.  The trouble I'm having is that either I can satisfy some of the hard constraints after 30 seconds of or so, and then the solver makes very little progress satisfying them constraints with additional minutes of termination.  I don't think the problem is over constrained; I also don't know how to help the local search process significantly increase the score.

My problem is a scheduling one, where I precalculate all possible times (intervals) that a sensor can observe objects prior to solving.   I've modeled the problem as follows:

1. Hard constraint - no intervals can overlap

   ```
    when
      $s1: A( interval!=null,$id: id, $doy : interval.doy, $interval: interval, $sensor: interval.getSensor())
     exists A( id > $id, interval!=null, $interval2: interval, $interval2.getSensor() == $sensor, $interval2.getDoy() == $doy, $interval.getStartSlot() <= $interval2.getEndSlot(), $interval.getEndSlot() >= $interval2.getStartSlot() )
    then
      scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-10000);
   ```
2. Medium constraint - every assignment should have an Interval

   ```
   when
     A(interval==null)
   then
     scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext,-100);
   ```
3. Soft constraint - maximize a property/value in the Interval class

   ```
   when
     $s1: A( interval!=null)
   then
     scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1 * $s1.getInterval().getSomeProperty())
   ```

A:  entity planning class; each instance is an assignment for a particular object (i.e has an member objectid that corresponds with one in the Interval class)

Interval:  planning variable class, all possible intervals (start time, stop time) for the sensor and objects

In A, I restrict access to B instances (intervals) to just those for the object associated with that assignment.   For my test case, there are 40000 or so Intervals, but only dozens for each object.  There are about 1100 instances of A (so dozens of possible Intervals for each one).

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"intervalRange"},strengthComparatorClass = IntervalStrengthComparator.class, nullable=true)
public Interval getInterval() {
    return interval;
}

@ValueRangeProvider(id = "intervalRange")
public List<Interval> getPossibleIntervalList() {
    return task.getAvailableIntervals();
}
```

In my solution class:
    //have tried commenting this out since the overall interval list does not apply to all A
    @ValueRangeProvider (id="intervalRangeAll")
    public List  getIntervalList() {
        return intervals;
    }

```
@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
public List<A> getAList() {
    return AList;
}
```

I've reviewed the documentation and tried a lot of things.  My problem is somewhat of a cross between the nurserostering and course scheduling examples, which I have looked at.  I am using the FIRST_FIT_DECREASING construction heuristic.

What I have tried:

1. Turning on and off nullable in the planning variable annotation for A.getInterval()
2. Late acceptance, Tabu, both.
3. Benchmarking. I wasn't seeing any problems and average
4. Adding an IntervalChangeFactory as a moveListFactory.   Restricting the custom ChangeMove to whether the interval can be accepted or not (i.e. enforcing or not the hard constraint in the IntervalChangeMove.isDoable).

Here is an example one, where most of the hard constraints are not satisfied, but the medium ones are:

```
[main] INFO org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving  started: time spent (202), best score (0hard/-112500medium/0soft), environment  mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (WELL44497B with seed 987654321).
[main] INFO org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase - Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (1125), time spent (2296), best score (-9100000hard/0medium/-72608soft).
[main] INFO org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase - Local Search phase (1) ended: step total (92507), time spent (30000), best score (-8850000hard/0medium/-74721soft).
[main] INFO org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving ended: time spent (30000), best score (-8850000hard/0medium/-74721soft), average calculate count per second (5643), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
```

So I don't understand is why the hard constraints can't be deal with by the search process.  Any my calculate count per second has dropped to below 10000 due to all the tinkering I've done.

Comment: See "Score trap" in docs: that hard constraint should probably penalize the overlapping time, instead of a fixed weight (regardless if they overlap a lot or a little).

Comment: I changed the hard constraint penalty to -10 and that didn't make a difference.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean by "penalize the overlapping time, instead of a fixed weight".    Of the 3 ways described in the doc, I'm already doing the first.  I tried the second with the overlap penalty constraint rule applied as a medium, then soft constraint (while keeping the hard) and that didn't make a difference.  The third way is more involved but I will take a look unless you have other suggestions.

Comment: Changing it to -10 still makes it a fixed weight, regardless of how much time is overlapped. Not sure how I can improve the docs. IIRC one of the training zip labs deals with this, see optaplanner.org -> learn -> training.

Comment: What is the alternative to fixed weight?

Comment: I misinterpreted your original parenthetical.  I believe by "penalize the overlapping" time you mean weight the hard constraint penalty by how much overlap in time there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not due to the **Score trap** (see docs, this is the first thing to fix), it's probably because it gets stuck in a local optima and there are no moves that go from 1 feasible solution to another feasible solution except those that don't really change much. There are several ways to deal with that:

- **Add course-grained moves** (but still leave the fine-grained moves such as ChangeMove in!). You can add **generic course grained moves** (such as the pillar moves) or add a **custom Move**. Don't start making smarter selectors that try to only select feasible moves, that's a bad idea (as it will kill your ACC or will limit your search space). Just mix in course grained moves (= diversification) to complement the fine grained moves (= intensification).
- A **better domain model** might help too. The Project Job Scheduling and Cheap Time scheduling examples have a domain model which naturally leads to a smaller search space while still allowing all feasible solutions.
- Increase Tabu list size, LA size or use a hard constraint in the SA starting temperature. But I presume you've tried that with the benchmarker.
- Turn on `TRACE` logging to see optaplanner's decision making. Only look at the part after it reaches the local optimum.
- In the future, I 'll also add Ruin&Recreate moves, which will be far less code than custom moves or a better domain model (but it will be less efficient).

Comment: This is a helpful list and will have long term benefits.  I had tried some size experiments -- your bullet #3.  I just stripped down to a simple approach, including only having the hard constraint about overlapping intervals.  I then realized that the test data was severely overconstrained and that the solver couldn't be expected to do well.